# R error "condition has length > 1 and only first element will be used"

Tags: r

I've searched through some of the previous posts on this subject and haven't found something to answer my question.

I'm doing the following:

```
brfss2013[, "hExcellent"] <- ifelse(brfss2013$genhlth == 'Excellent') 1, 0
```

> Error: unexpected numeric constant in "brfss2013[, "hExcellent"] <- ifelse(brfss2013$genhlth == 'Excellent') 1"

Not sure what the problem is.  I'm simply trying to place a 1 or 0 in my new column based on what my evaluation of the condition is.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Your closing parentheses is in the wrong place. Try `ifelse(brfss2013$genhlth == 'Excellent', 1, 0)`

Comment: Don't use `ifelse`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Your `ifelse` syntax is incorrect. If should be `ifelse(condition, TRUE, FALSE)` (note the brackets). See also `?ifelse`.
2. **More importantly**, since you return 1 or 0 (depending on the condition), you don't need `ifelse` at all.

   ```
   brfss2013[, "hExcellent"] <- +(brfss2013$genhlth == 'Excellent')
   ```

   suffices and is faster. The unary operator `+` is explained in `` ?`+` ``.

   Alternatively you can also use `as.integer`

   ```
   brfss2013[, "hExcellent"] <- as.integer(brfss2013$genhlth == 'Excellent')
   ```

---

Lastly and for future posts, it's always better to include some form of minimal representative sample data to make your issue/problem/error reproducible. Ideally, potential SO respondents should be able to copy&paste your sample data and code into a terminal, and reproduce the issue that you describe. To improve your post, take a look at what to consider when providing a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: This makes sense.  Thank you very much Maurits.  Definitely had misplaced brackets and commas.
I didn't included a code snipet as I thought the question was simple enough that people looking at it could answer but I'll do that next time.  Thanks again.

Comment: You're very welcome @Bill and welcome to SO!